How to limit the results to the first 3 rows per group?
I have the following query:
SELECT
    codigov, rut, cantidad,referencia
FROM h
WHERE tipomov="R"
ORDER BY referencia,codigo DESC

codigo| rut | cantidad |referencia
5     | 1   |  10      |15
5     | 4   |  10      |14
7     | 01  |  30      |13
4     | 81  |  40      |12
5     | 41  |  55      |11
5     | 41  |  31      |10
7     | 11  |  51      |9
9     | 13  |  31      |8
1     | 11  |  25      |7
5     | 12  |  43      |6
5     | 31  |  31      |5
1     | 13  |  13      |4
1     | 12  |  31      |3
1     | 62  |  13      |2 
5     | 31  |  13      |1

What I want to obtain is a limit of 3 per code, ordered by descending reference and then by code. That is, an example like this:
codigo| rut | cantidad |referencia
5     | 1   |  10      |15
5     | 4   |  10      |14
5     | 41  |  31      |10
1     | 11  |  25      |7
1     | 13  |  13      |4
1     | 12  |  31      |3
7     | 01  |  30      |13
4     | 81  |  40      |12
10    | 41  |  55      |11    
7     | 11  |  51      |9
9     | 13  |  31      |8
10    | 12  |  43      |6    
25    | 31  |  13      |1

In this case, code 5 and one are limited by 3 records and ordered.
There is the ROW_NUMBER() OVER function, but in my version of MySql, it does not have it.
If anyone has an idea, I would appreciate it, thank you in advance.

if your version of mysql does not have it, you are running a version that is no longer supported and no longer receiving security updates; consider it insecure and update as soon as you can.
